# Wrapper, Filter and Servlet

Tags: servlets, filter, wrapper

since I am new to Servlet programming, it is possible that I ask a basic question.

I am writing an application where a Filter gets the response from a servlet, and does some computation with it. I found out that I need a wrapper class to catch the response.

My question now is why the wrapper is needed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only you can answer this question as you already found out that you need a wrapper class :-) What are you trying to achieve? And no, a wrapper (request/response) is not always necessary...

Comment: as far as I understood it, when I want to catch the Servlet response and do something with it in my filter, I need a wrapper. Is that correct? What about this case: I have a form, where a user can type in username and some text. This should then be displayed on another page. I know a servlet can take the input parameters and forward to another page. Can I achieve the same with a filter?

Comment: 1. No, who told you that (an example might help here)? 2. I'd rather not implement business logic in a filter, why you think a filter is the better choice?

Comment: I think I'm just really confused with what both things are for ...

Comment: In general, you should use filters for non-functional aspects. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html for some examples.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**1) Lets first understand how `Request` and `Request Filter` work:**

When, lets say client, makes a request to servlet, it goes through container. Container decides what servlet `Request` needs to be forwarded to. Which means, container is in total control.

Container control makes implementing *request filter* easy because we can just let container know that the `Request` should go to *filter* first and then to servlet. Because container is in total control. So implementing *request* filter is easy.

**2) Now lets understand how `Response` and `Response Filter` work:**

When container invokes Servlet service methods, it passes 2 objects to the methods, `Request` and `Response`.

This simply means that Servlet is in total control to send the response back to client. How ?

Because `Response` object has the *pointer* to `Output Stream Writer` object. Which means, once Servlet finishes processing the request, it will straight write the `Response` back to the client using *pointer* to `Output Writer Stream` object. So, Servlet won't wait for anyone (middle men like filter) and straight serve the client. By the time, it will be too late to intervene.

**So, what's the solutions ?**

`Wrapper` is our solution.

**How Wrapper works ?**

So, before container passes the real `Request` and `Response` objects to Servlet, we will wrap our `Response` object and then send the `Real Request` and `Wrapped Response` objects to the Servlet service methods.

So now, Servlet has pointer to our `Wrapped Output Stream Writer` object and not the `Real Response Output Stream Writer` object. So, when Servlet finishes the request, it will write the response to our `Wrapped Stream` and then Our `Wrapped Response Object` will write back to `Real Response Writer Stream`.

**Moral of the story:** Use `wrapper` when dealing with `Response`. `Request` doesn't need wrapper concept.

Comment: Request might need a wrapper concept, i.e. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/anti-cross-site-scripting-xss-filter.html