# What could be advantage of ServletRequestWrapper over Filter?

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16492727/2160175) it was cleary stated why `ServletResponseWrapper` can be useful. What about `ServletRequestWrapper`? What real application may use a `ServletRequestWrapper` for if in fact all could be achieved with just a Filter? Can somebody provide a scenario?

Comment: What is your use case? Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4449096/1988304) . If you have to read the body of a HTTP request multiple times, you can use a HttpRequestWrapper for caching the body.

Comment: You can find real world use cases here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22extends+HttpServletRequestWrapper%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question **is not** to use an implementation `Filter` **or** a `ServletRequestWrapper` / `ServletResponseWrapper` . The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16492727/2160175) that you linked in your question is good, but it doesn't point out an important fact: wrappers are often, or even mostly, created during the execution of the method `doFilter()` in a class which implements the interface `Filter`.

Take a careful look at the links which BalusC has posted in his comment.